# Using a do/while loop to error check user input

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, do-while

Hi I am having trouble with a homework assignment. The program is using two different methods to average and display a user defined set of numbers. I figured all of that out, but I am having difficulty with the error checking. I do not want the user to be able to say that they want to average a negative or zero amount of numbers at the beginning so I am trying to use a if/else statement and a do while loop to display an error message to the user as well as give them the option to try again.

When the user enters a 1 to try the program over again after entering an invalid number, the program allows the user to try again. However once they enter everything in correctly and complete the program, the program starts over again. I want the program to end once the program is completed correctly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Defining the variables in main method
    int inputNumber;
    int repeat = 0;

    //Creating the array and checking for negative or no numbers using do..while and if..else
    do
    {
        String aStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many numbers would you like to be averaged?");
        inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(aStr);

            if(inputNumber <= 0)
            {
                String errorStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Cannot be a negative number or a zero. Press 1 to try again.");
                repeat = Integer.parseInt(errorStr);
            }
            else
            {
                double[] array = new double[inputNumber];
                displayAverage(average(array));
            } 
    } while (repeat == 1);
} // end main

// Creating a method called "average" that calculates and returns the average to main
public static double average(double [] methodArray)
{
    // Defining variables in average method
    int index;
    double total = 0;
    double average;

    // Taking user inputed numbers and adding them up
    for(index = 0; index < methodArray.length; index++)
    {
        String bStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number " + (index + 1));
        methodArray[index] = Double.parseDouble(bStr);

        total = total + methodArray[index];
    }
    // Calculating the average
    average = total/index;
    return average;
} //end average method

// Creating a method called "displayAverage" that displays the average in a dialog box
public static void displayAverage(double returnedAverage)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average of all your numbers is " + returnedAverage);
}
```

} //end class

Comment: what is your problem exactly? you cannot understand meaning of `do-while`?  Or you have problem in doing checking of validity of input? Or you have problem in getting more than 1 input?

Comment: The problem I'm having is having to do with the checking of validity of input. I seem to either be using the do-while incorrectly or I have it located in the incorrect place from the looks of some of the answers/comments.

Comment: Next time it will be much better if you can 1. write a smaller program which only demonstrate the problem (calculateAverage and displayAverage is simply unrelated) , and 2. be clear on the expected behavior and the problematic behavior you encountered.   In a lot of cases, by doing 1, you can figure out the solution by yourself.

Comment: Sorry about that. This is my first programming class and the first time using StackOverflow. I wasn't sure how much detail from my program was needed for people to understand my problem. Thanks for the tips. I will remember them for next time.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that after the user tries again and enters valid input, you never change the value of `repeat` so the loop will never exit. In the `else` if your `if-else` within the loop, you need to reassign `repeat` to something other than 1 so the loop can exit!

Answer (score 0):

To loop until you get valid input, try something like this: Set the `validInput` boolean to true only when the input is valid.

```
boolean validInput = false;
while (!validInput) {
    //get input from user
    if (userInputIsValid) { //however this is done
        validInput = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is specifically about the proper use of do/while. Although this code is equivalent, it is not about what the OP asked.

Comment: @hfontanez I understood the question to be about prompting the user for input, getting the input, looping if input is bad and breaking the loop if it's good. The OP happened to have used a `do-while loop`, but unnecessarily.

Comment: @hfontanez yts is correct. Sorry I should have been more clear. I don't necessarily have to use a do-while loop, its just the only way I currently know how to repeat my program when checking for valid input. Before I attempted to use the do-while, I was only using an if-else statement to check for valid input, but the issue with that was that my program would simply notify the user of the error and then terminate the program.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
    boolean repeat = false;

    do
    {
        String aStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "How many numbers would you like to be averaged?");
        try
        {
            inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(aStr);
            if (inputNumber <= 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Input must be a number greater than zero. Try again.",
                    "ERROR: Invalid input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                repeat = true;
            }
            else
            {
                double[] array = new double[inputNumber];
                displayAverage(average(array));
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Input must be a numeric string. Try again",
                    "ERROR: Invalid input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            repeat = true;
        }

    } while (repeat);
```

The try/catch is needed to handle invalid numeric strings like a blank text field, or other non-numeric characters.

You may also want to include additional logic to handle cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is another answer given the correct (I believe it is) answer, I would want to elaborate a bit more.

This is the psuedo code:

```
do {
    inputNumber = getInput();
    if(inputNumber <= 0) {
        displayErrorMessage();
        repeat = 1;       // your logic makes no sense when people input non-1
    } else {
        calculateAverage(inputNumber);
    }    
} while (repeat == 1)
```

The problem is quite obvious: once you got an invalid `inputNumber`, you set `repeat = 1` which cause `do-while` loop to continue again.  However afterwards, even the user input a valid `inputNumber`, `repeat` keeps on being 1, and everytime it hit the check in `while(repeat ==1)` it will still evaluate to true.

I will strongly suggest you to learn to use debugger in basic way, so that you can trace through your code and you will easily identify the problem by seeing it keep on looping even you input valid number, because `repeat` is always 1.

Another suggestion is to rewrite a bit your code to make it easier to understand.  Instead of naming that repeat which means nothing, you can write the things as:

```
boolean inputIsValid= false;
do {
    inputNumber = getInput();

    inputIsValid= verifyInput(inputNumber);

    if ( inputIsValid) {
       calculateAverage(inputNumber);
    } else {
       displayErrorMessage();
    } 
} while ( ! inputIsValid)
```

The flow, imho, is more intuitive.

This is only the first step.  You can even better wrap the get input logic in a separate method, so that the main logic looks like:

```
inputNumber = getInput();
calculateAverage(inputNumber);
```

and you put the looping in `getInput()`.  Looks clearer isn't it?